# Twilio Client Chat - Send media message

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

How can I send media message in Chat Client ? I'm using JS SDK and base on the tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/media-support, but getting error. I'm using the `sendMessage` method like this:

```
channel.sendMessage({ contentType: 'image/png', media: 'base64 string image' });
```

The error message:

```
{
  commandId: "e289ff36-4d9d-4fdb-8e36-46078c7228ef"
  response {
    responseTime: "2017-10-02T00:20:26.675Z"
    status: 50107
    statusText:"User unauthorized for command"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Twilio Chat dev is here)

In order to be able to send multimedia messages, user should have a sendMediaMessage permission for the role used (and sendMessage one as well -- but this most likely is already there).

See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/media-support#required-role-permission for the details.

Comment: thanks, I thought the permission for media message is there by default. I've managed to add the permission now.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is solved. It is there by default only for newly created service instances.